# correct blending between multiple volumes in opengl

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader, raycasting, alphablending, blending

I draw multiple 3d shapes in cube volumes with raycasting in fragment shader, like described here:
https://github.com/bagobor/opengl33_dev_cookbook_2013/blob/master/Chapter7/GPURaycasting/shaders/raycaster.frag

```
    float prev_alpha = sample - (sample * vFragColor.a);
    vFragColor.rgb = prev_alpha * vec3(sample) + vFragColor.rgb; 
    vFragColor.a += prev_alpha;
```

It goes from front to back of the raycast and accumulates the alpha in each step.
For alpha blending i use this settings:

```
glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.01);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

I have an blending problem, when i draw multiple volumes. Fully transparent parts of cubes are drawn in front non-transparent parts of others. How can i fix this, discard the transparent parts of the cubes?
(Rearranging the array of volumes to its xyz position dont work, because i can turn the camera)

[image]

Comment: fixed it. i had to disable depth test for this.

Comment: If your answer is solved, then please post an answer or delete it altogether.

Comment: Even with disabled depth test, results will still depend on draw order.

Comment: @derhass thats right. do you know a better solution, without changing draw order?